# Slow data Selection from MDB file to C# Desktop application

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

Although everything is correct, but data selection process is very slow in my Application, while retriving data from access .mdb file. Is there any idea that data can be accessed fast. Is there any mechanism??
This below code Runs when Button Clicked .

```
    public class GetData   {
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(DatabseConnection.ConnectionStringAccessDatabase);

    public string lblPolicyNumber,              lblInsuredName,              lblIssuedDatePolicy,              lblStatusPolicy,
          lblModalPremium,              lblDueDate,              lblNextDueDate,              lblAgentCode,
          lblMode,              lblType1,              lblAmount1,              lblDate1,              lblPremAmt1,
          lblDueDate1,              lbPaidDate1,              lblPremAmt2,              lblDueDate2,
          lblPaidDate2,              lblPremAmt3,              lbDueDate3,              lblPadiDate3,
          lblOwnersName,              lblOwnersCode,              lblAddress1,              lblAddress2,
          lblPlan,              lblCoverageAmt,              lblSex,              lblBirthDate,              lblAge,
          lblAutomaticPrmloan,              lblAPLCount,              lblLoanType,              lblLoanPrincipleamt,
          lblLoanDate,              lblRatedNotRated,              lblUnderWritingApproved              , LateFee,
          TotalAmountDue,              AmountInDeposit,              NetPayableAmount,              Overdueprem,
          CurrentPremiumDue, lblPMFlastUpdated               = null;
    public void getData(string policyNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Please Download the File From the Server, Or Contact IT Department"); }
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();


        cmd.CommandText = "(Select capolnum, cainame, iss_dte, castatus, mod_prm, due_dte1, nxt_due, agent_code, cabmode, casustyp1, casusamt1, casusdate1, chbldpm1,  pd_dte1, chbldpm2, due_dte2, pd_dte2, chbldpm3, due_dte3, pd_dte3 , caoname, ocode, Addr1, addr2, plan, cbcovamt, cbsex, birth_dte, cbissage, apl, as400_cl_aplcnt, as400_cl_lntype, as400_cl_lnprinc, apl_date, cstype, approved FROM agy_pmf where capolnum ='" + policyNumber + "' )";
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {

            SetData.lblPolicyNumber = lblPolicyNumber = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            SetData.lblInsuredName = lblInsuredName = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
            lblIssuedDatePolicy = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
            lblStatusPolicy = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
            lblModalPremium = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
            lblDueDate = dr.GetValue(6).ToString();
            lblNextDueDate = dr.GetValue(6).ToString();
            lblAgentCode = dr.GetValue(7).ToString();
            SetData.lblMode = lblMode = dr.GetValue(8).ToString();
            lblType1 = dr.GetValue(9).ToString();
            lblAmount1 = dr.GetValue(10).ToString();
            lblDate1 = dr.GetValue(11).ToString();
            lblPremAmt1 = dr.GetValue(12).ToString();
            lblDueDate1 = dr.GetValue(5).ToString();
            lbPaidDate1 = dr.GetValue(13).ToString();
            lblPremAmt2 = dr.GetValue(14).ToString();
            lblDueDate2 = dr.GetValue(15).ToString();
            lblPaidDate2 = dr.GetValue(16).ToString();
            lblPremAmt3 = dr.GetValue(17).ToString();
            lbDueDate3 = dr.GetValue(18).ToString();
            lblPadiDate3 = dr.GetValue(19).ToString();
            lblOwnersName = dr.GetValue(20).ToString();
            lblOwnersCode = dr.GetValue(21).ToString();
            lblAddress1 = dr.GetValue(22).ToString();
            lblAddress2 = dr.GetValue(23).ToString();
            lblPlan = dr.GetValue(24).ToString();
            lblCoverageAmt = dr.GetValue(25).ToString();
            lblSex = dr.GetValue(26).ToString();
            lblBirthDate = dr.GetValue(27).ToString();
            lblAge = dr.GetValue(28).ToString();
            lblAutomaticPrmloan = dr.GetValue(29).ToString();
            lblAPLCount = dr.GetValue(30).ToString();
            lblLoanType = dr.GetValue(31).ToString();
            lblLoanPrincipleamt = dr.GetValue(32).ToString();
            lblLoanDate = dr.GetValue(33).ToString();
            lblRatedNotRated = dr.GetValue(34).ToString();
            lblUnderWritingApproved = dr.GetValue(35).ToString();
            con.Close();

        }

      }}
```

Comment: Is the [capolnum] field indexed? (Also, get rid of the brackets around your SQL statement in `cmd.CommandText`; they are not necessary.)

Comment: Do you mean to close the connection after every dr.Read?